# Lookup the Most Recent Past Date Based on Criteria

Tags: excel-formula

Here is my sample data

| Date | Vendor | Func | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 1 | AB |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 2 | AC |
| 1/1/2023 | B | 3 | AD |
| 1/2/2023 | A | 1 | AB |
| 1/2/2023 | A | 2 | AC |
| 1/2/2023 | B | 3 | AD |
| 1/4/2023 | A | 1 | AB |
| 1/4/2023 | A | 2 | AC |
| 1/4/2023 | B | 3 | AD |
| 1/5/2023 | A | 1 | AB |
| 1/5/2023 | A | 2 | AC |
| 1/5/2023 | B | 3 | AD |

Output:

| Date | Vendor | Func | Name | Recent_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 1 | AB | Null |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 2 | AC | Null |
| 1/1/2023 | B | 3 | AD | Null |
| 1/2/2023 | A | 1 | AB | 1/1/2023 |
| 1/2/2023 | A | 2 | AC | 1/1/2023 |
| 1/2/2023 | B | 3 | AD | 1/1/2023 |
| 1/4/2023 | A | 1 | AB | 1/2/2023 |
| 1/4/2023 | A | 2 | AC | 1/2/2023 |
| 1/4/2023 | B | 3 | AD | 1/2/2023 |
| 1/5/2023 | A | 1 | AB | 1/4/2023 |
| 1/5/2023 | A | 2 | AC | 1/4/2023 |
| 1/5/2023 | B | 3 | AD | 1/4/2023 |

What makes row unique : Date+Func columns

For Date 1/1/2023:The previous past date is not listed in the data,it should return null

For Date 1/2/2023: Similarly,it should return 1/1/2023

For Date 1/4/2023:Similarly,it should return 1/2/2023

For Date 1/5/2023:Similarly,it should return 1/4/2023

Can someone help me with what excel function to use to get the expected ouput (Recent_Date) as shown above?

I tried using index and match for this but still not working

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned INDEX/MATCH, here's the solution using that:

```
=INDEX(DateColumn;MATCH(DateValue-1;DateColumn;1))
```

where `DateValue` refers to the date cell of the same row.

Of course, there's also the `XLOOKUP` option which is maybe a bit more legible:

```
=XLOOKUP(DateValue-1;DateColumn;DateColumn;;-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I use the above formula =INDEX(DateColumn;MATCH(DateValue-1;DateColumn;1)) ,for Date 1/4/2023 it should return 1/2/2023 instead of 1/3/2023

Comment: @poojamalage No problem! The formula does return 1/2/2023 at least for the example data above. Are you sure you do not have a 1/3/2023 date somewhere in your data?

Comment: Yes, there are scenarios where 1/3/2023 is not there.